# How to implement bar code scanner in Java?

Tags: java, barcode-scanner, point-of-sale

I have developed a Point of Sale (POS) system in Java.

Now I want to implement bar code functionality in the program: like I purchase a bar code scanner and want to implement it with my program, and also to generate bar codes.

Is it possible?

Comment: Depending on your scanner, you could set up your program to read directly from it (rather than as a keyboard wedge - requiring input focus first) here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146840/barcode-scanner-implementation-on-java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this open source library.
[zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/updates/list)

Answer (score 3):

Many barcode scanners appear indistinguishable from USB keyboards from the perspective of Java. So a barcode scan "looks like" a bunch of very rapid key events. (It's a non-trivial exercise to sort the scans from the "normal" keystrokes, so this has ramifications on the design of your user interface.